# Pass the value to database in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Am trying to save the images to the database using the asp.net webapi. In this controller am saving the image into my `/Content/Banner/` Folder.

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("PostBanner")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostBannerImage()
        {
            Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            try
            {
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
                if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 1; //Size = 1 MB  

                    IList<string> AllowedFileExtensions = new List<string> { ".jpg", ".gif", ".png" };
                    var ext = postedFile.FileName.Substring(postedFile.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'));
                    var extension = ext.ToLower();
                    if (!AllowedFileExtensions.Contains(extension))
                    {

                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload image of type .jpg,.gif,.png.");

                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else if (postedFile.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                    {

                        var message = string.Format("Please Upload a file upto 1 mb.");

                        dict.Add("error", message);
                        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, dict);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Banner/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
                    }
                }

                var message1 = string.Format("Image Updated Successfully.");
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, message1); ;
            }

            var res = string.Format("Please Upload a image.");
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var res = string.Format("some Message");
            dict.Add("error", res);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, dict);
        }
    }
```

Now what i need to **send** this **filePath** to **database**. I know i just need to pass this file path to the following service controller. But i dont know how to pass it. could anyone help me to solve this problem.

This Is my services.cs

```
 public async Task<int?> Addbanner(DisplayBannersDto dto)
        {
            try
            {
                var d = _dbContext.Banners
            .FirstOrDefault();



                d.Banner_Description = dto.Description;
                d.Banner_Location = dto.Location;


                //mark entry as modifed
                _dbContext.Entry(d).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                return d.Banner_Id;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

This is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("AddBanner")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> AddBanner(DisplayBannersDto dto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return BadRequest(ModelState);

            int? result = await _service.Addbanner(dto);
            return Ok();

        }
```

Comment: Do you want to save the image path from inside of the PostBannerImage() API or do you want to invoke a second API to do the database saving?

Comment: @JoseFrancis i want to invoke a second API to do the database saving..

Comment: So, why don't you return the "filepath" from the PostBannerImage(), receive at the client then call the second API after inserting the same to DisplayBannersDto.

Comment: am new to the asp.net how can i do that? can u help me to solve this?

Comment: Did that work ?

Comment: hi sorry for late. and i could not get the response. in my DTO.
when try this code. its shows responce doesnot exist in this context...

Comment: The two lines of code around  response.Content.ToString() is for the client application. Where did you use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your else condition like below:

```
else
{
    var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Banner/" + postedFile.FileName + extension);
                        postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

    return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Created,
                Content = new StringContent(filePath, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };
}
```

Now, you have the filepath in the content of the API response.

and use that response like :

```
var displayBannersDto = new DisplayBannersDto();
displayBannersDto.Banner_Location = response.Content.ToString();
```

then call your AddBanner() API with displayBannersDto  as the dto.